# How can I reverse map using reflection

Tags: dictionary, go, reflection

I am studying `reflect` in Go and trying to implement function which get `map` and return another `map`, where keys will be values and values will be keys.

Example:

```
m := map[string]int{"one": 1, "two": 2}
fmt.Println(ReverseMap(m)) // {1: "one", 2: "two"}
```

Here is my code:

```
func ReverseMap(in interface{}) interface{} {

    var out reflect.Value
    v := reflect.ValueOf(in)
    if v.Kind() == reflect.Map {
        for idx, key := range v.MapKeys() {
            value := v.MapIndex(key)
            if idx == 0 {
                mapType := reflect.MapOf(reflect.TypeOf(value), reflect.TypeOf(key))
                out = reflect.MakeMap(mapType)
            }
            out.SetMapIndex(value, key)
        }
    }
    return out
}
```

This code `panic` with error:

> panic: reflect.Value.SetMapIndex: value of type int is not assignable to type reflect.Value

I think the reason of this error is the declaration of `out` variable, but I don't know how to declare it correctly, if I don't know the type of this variable.

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `key` and `value` are of type [`reflect.Value`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value), so passing them to [`reflect.TypeOf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#TypeOf) will not return the type descriptors of the key and value types of the map (`string` and `int`), but instead the type descriptor of the `reflect.Value` type itself.

Instead simply call their [`Value.Type()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Type) method:

```
mapType := reflect.MapOf(value.Type(), key.Type())
```

With this it'll (almost) work and print (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/UAZw_EicQzm)):

```
map[1:one 2:two]
```

I wrote "almost" because you're returning a `reflect.Value`, not a `map`. But if a `reflect.Value` is passed to the [`fmt`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) package, it prints the value wrapped inside it:

> If the operand is a reflect.Value, the operand is replaced by the concrete value that it holds, and printing continues with the next rule.

So you should call [`Value.Interface()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Interface) on `out` before returning it.

It's easier to return early if the kind is not map, so you can create the map right after that:

```
func ReverseMap(in interface{}) interface{} {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(in)
    if v.Kind() != reflect.Map {
        return nil
    }

    mapType := reflect.MapOf(v.Type().Elem(), v.Type().Key())
    out := reflect.MakeMap(mapType)

    for _, key := range v.MapKeys() {
        out.SetMapIndex(v.MapIndex(key), key)
    }

    return out.Interface()
}
```

Try this variant on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/3BLwlD9Ugu4).

Another approach may be using [`Value.MapRange()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.MapRange):

```
for iter := v.MapRange(); iter.Next(); {
    out.SetMapIndex(iter.Value(), iter.Key())
}
```

Try this variant on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/8QSmbafE_ap).